# Image search engine using opencv

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I was trying to build an Image search engine using Opencv in Python.Instead using color histogram, I was trying to use some feature detecting algo like SIFT so that I could save the descriptors of the existing images in a file.
While searching I would then match the descriptors of query image with the file(in which descriptors of other images are stored) and display the best results.
The problem is that how to store the descriptors of thousand's of images efficiently.Is there any more efficient method??
Any help would be greatly appreciated..